# What is this trigonometric graph?

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I polar graphed $r=\sin(1.31459x)$ instead of $r=\sin(1.31459\theta)$, which uses the variable $x$ instead of $\theta$.  Mac Grapher provides the result pictured below.  I'm confused because $x$ should not be a variable in a polar graph, yet here is the result.

**Question 1** Does anyone know what I actually graphed and why it worked with the variable $x$ instead of $\theta$?

Graph $r = \sin(1.31459x)$:

[image: A]

Comment: [Here's what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEZA0.jpg)

Comment: The $x$ isn't merely a replacement for $\theta$. You've graphed the implicit curve $r=\sin(k r\cos\theta)$, which is consistent with the cartesian-polar conversion $x=r\cos\theta$. (You can compare the graphs in Grapher.)

Comment: For comparison, changing coordinates to Cartesian gives the same [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+sqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29+%3D+sin%28%CF%80+x%29%2C+x+from+-1+to+1%2C+y+from+-1+to+1)

Comment: @user170231 Helpful.  How did you convert $r = sin(1.3459 r cos\theta)$ to $\sqrt {x^2 + y^2} = sin(\pi x)$?  I see on wiki $x = r cos(\theta), y = r sin(\theta), r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, but it's parametric.  Also confused how $\pi$ is part of the solution.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the coefficient as $3.14159\approx\pi$. The actual value of the coefficient is irrelevant, as ultimately I just replaced $x=r\cos(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

You may use polar co-ordinates $(r,t)$ $x=r\cos t, y=r \sin t$ and use ContourPlot of Mathematica for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sin(\pi x),x\in(0,1), y\in(-1,1).$

Answer (score 0):

Grapher is automatically converting $x$ into $r cos \theta$.  The polar form is $r = sin(k r cos(\theta))$, where $k = \frac {\pi} {10} + 1$.  The Cartesian form is $\sqrt {x^2 + y^2} = sin(kx)$.